# Can a muslim practice yoga?

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices

Considering the origins and the foundations of the [yoga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga), can a muslim practice yoga as body activity instead as a set of tenets and beliefs?

Comment: The Prophet (SAWS) allowed recitation in ruqya as long as there is no shirk in it. So I guess the same should hold for things like yoga and martial arts like judo, tai chi, and so on. As long as there is no shirk in it, my understanding is that there is no harm in doing it. However I am no scholar, so keep an eye on the other answers.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/5604/584) helps?

Comment: The thing about Yoga, as we know it today, is that it's *not* the ancient Hindu spiritual practice. It has the same basis, but is used for it's physical properties as a form of recreation and sport.

Answer (score 8):

This is based from country which I resides:

In Malaysia, Fatwa Council has declared that yoga is haram (prohibited) in Islam and Muslims are banned from practising it because incorporate physical movements, religious elements together with chants and worshipping. However  merely doing the physical movements of yoga without the worshipping and chanting **not** considered haram.

Answer (score 1):

> Practicing Yoga has no prohibition if it's beneficial. If the Yoga is
>   a sport for mind and body, and is not accompanied by any haram and
>   sin, then it's not prohibited.

from:

Resaale Estefta'at Ayatollah Behjat, Volume 4, Page 569, Question 6506

&
Resaale Estefta'at Ayatollah Makarem Shirazi, Volume 3, Question 201

My Opinion:

Don't be closed mind. As the quote, if it's not accompanied by any obvious Haram, then it must be OK.

Comment: Islam has so many good things. But it has a bad reputation all over the world. This has so many reasons. among theme are wrong interpretation and intentional wrong interpretation. Besides, the quote about yoga deserved an upvote, not downvote.

Comment: *"Islam is not strict about anything."* I don't think so. Islam is strict on it's rule and so is nature.

Comment: Plus I don't think the *"My Opinion"* say anything important and the answer can do without it.

Comment: Well. you'r right, Islam is strict. I've edited my answer. but I stand on my opinion. Don't be closed mind.

Answer (score 1):

there is a difference between meaning of yoga.
In my country yoga is not haram and everyone can do it.
in different countries yoga is done in different ways.
so this can't be a specific haram or halal sport because of variations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will do shirk if you do Yoga as Yoga is not an exercise but a way of reaching god in Hinduism. Hindus every morning do SuryaNamaskar incase to the people have not been enlightened as yet should know that it is Yoga. This Yoga pose is basically getting closer to the god of Sun. Each Yoga has its own religious background and hence doing Yoga will definitely make you a shirk.

Comment: Thanks for your response. you can enhance it by finding [[https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer]]

Answer (score 0):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga),

> Various traditions of yoga are found in Hinduism, Buddhism and Jainism.[5][6][7][6] In Hinduism, yoga is one of the six āstika schools (accepts authority of Vedas)[8] of Hindu philosophy.[9] Yoga is also an important part of Vajrayana and Tibetan Buddhist philosophy.

It is clear this is Haram since it is associated with beliefs muslims don't agree with. Besides, Islam came with other halal ways(Salah, duaa, etc...) to reach someone's permanent mind of state . We don't have to follow other ways when Allah showed us the true way to reach tranquility and peace.

If you want to practice Yoga health purposes, you can use other ways which is not associated with any religion such as p90 training or any recommended training online.

Comment: technically speaking... even P90x has women with inappropriate cloths... but i guess one can always just learn about the exercises, timing, proper form and just do the P90x program without looking at the video.